# System.Configuration.ConfigurationException when running a serviece build on .NET 4.0 on Windows Server 2012

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, windows, wcf

Good Day.

I have an existing windows service that is running well on Windows Service 2003 using or .NET 4.0. I am trying to install the same service on Windows Service 2012 and was successful. However, when I run the service, I got the error below. I believe Windows Server support 4.5 which also includes 4.0, is this correct?

Can anyone help me identify why I'm getting the message below?

```
Log Name:      Application
Source:        .NET Runtime
Date:          8/17/2015 5:56:56 AM
Event ID:      1026
Task Category: None
Level:         Error
Keywords:      Classic
User:          N/A
Computer:      usa0300vm1598.na.xerox.net
Description:
Application: ATLAS_LETTERPROCESS.SERVICE.exe
Framework Version: v4.0.30319
```

```
Description: The process was terminated due to an unhandled exception.
Exception Info: System.Configuration.ConfigurationErrorsException
Stack:
   at System.Configuration.ClientConfigurationSystem.EnsureInit(System.String)
   at System.Configuration.ClientConfigurationSystem.PrepareClientConfigSystem(System.String)
   at System.Configuration.ClientConfigurationSystem.System.Configuration.Internal.IInternalConfigSystem.GetSection(System.String)
   at System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.get_AppSettings()
   at ATLAS_LETTERPROCESS.SERVICE.AtlasLetterProcess..ctor()
   at ATLAS_LETTERPROCESS.SERVICE.Program.Main()
```

Event Xml:

```xml
<Event xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2004/08/events/event">
  <System>
    <Provider Name=".NET Runtime" />
    <EventID Qualifiers="0">1026</EventID>
    <Level>2</Level>
    <Task>0</Task>
    <Keywords>0x80000000000000</Keywords>
    <TimeCreated SystemTime="2015-08-17T09:56:56.000000000Z" />
    <EventRecordID>58020</EventRecordID>
    <Channel>Application</Channel>
    <Computer>usa0300vm1598.na.xerox.net</Computer>
    <Security />
  </System>
  <EventData>
    <Data>Application: ATLAS_LETTERPROCESS.SERVICE.exe

Framework Version: v4.0.30319  
Description: The process was terminated due to an unhandled exception.

Exception Info: System.Configuration.ConfigurationErrorsException
Stack:
   at System.Configuration.ClientConfigurationSystem.EnsureInit(System.String)
   at System.Configuration.ClientConfigurationSystem.PrepareClientConfigSystem(System.String)
   at System.Configuration.ClientConfigurationSystem.System.Configuration.Internal.IInternalConfigSystem.GetSection(System.String)
   at System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.get_AppSettings()
   at ATLAS_LETTERPROCESS.SERVICE.AtlasLetterProcess..ctor()
   at ATLAS_LETTERPROCESS.SERVICE.Program.Main()
</Data>
  </EventData>
</Event>
```

Below is the current app.config file

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <sectionGroup name="applicationSettings" type="System.Configuration.ApplicationSettingsGroup, System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" >
      <section name="ATLAS_LETTERPROCESS.Common.Properties.Settings" type="System.Configuration.ClientSettingsSection, System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
    </sectionGroup>
  </configSections>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="Intentionally Hidden" connectionString="metadata=res://*/AtlasLetterProcess.csdl|res://*/AtlasLetterProcess.ssdl|res://*/AtlasLetterProcess.msl;provider=Oracle.DataAccess.Client;provider connection string=&quot;DATA SOURCE=(DESCRIPTION = (ADDRESS_LIST = (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = Intentionally Hidden)(PORT = Intentionally Hidden))) (CONNECT_DATA = (SERVICE_NAME = Intentionally Hidden)));User Id= Intentionally Hidden;Password=Intentionally Hidden;&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
  <oracle.dataaccess.client>
    <settings>

      <add name="Intentionally Hidden" value="implicitRefCursor bindinfo='mode=Output'"/>

      <add name="Intentionally Hidden" value="implicitRefCursor metadata='ColumnName=TL_LETTER_ID;
           BaseColumnName=TL_LETTER_ID; BaseSchemaName=CMS_USER;BaseTableName=TBL_LETTER;
           NativeDataType=number;ProviderType=Int32'"/>

      <add name="Intentionally Hidden" value="implicitRefCursor metadata='ColumnName=TL_ATLAS_KEY_ID;
           BaseSchemaName=CMS_USER;BaseTableName=TBL_LETTER;NativeDataType=varchar2;ProviderType=varchar2;ProviderDBType=String;
                 DataType=System.String;AllowDBNull=true'"/>

      <add name="Intentionally Hidden" value="implicitRefCursor metadata='ColumnName=TL_INPUT_XML;
           BaseSchemaName=CMS_USER;BaseTableName=TBL_LETTER;
           NativeDataType=clob;ProviderType=Clob'"/>

      <add name="Intentionally Hidden" value="implicitRefCursor metadata='ColumnName=TL_DART_URL;BaseSchemaName=CMS_USER;
                 BaseTableName=TBL_LETTER;NativeDataType=varchar2;ProviderType=Varchar2;ProviderDBType=String;
                 DataType=System.String;AllowDBNull=true'"/>

      <add name="Intentionally Hidden" value="implicitRefCursor metadata='ColumnName=TL_STATUS;BaseSchemaName=CMS_USER;
                 BaseTableName=TBL_LETTER;NativeDataType=char;ProviderType=char;ProviderDBType=String;ColumnSize=2;
                 DataType=System.String;AllowDBNull=true'"/>

      <add name="Intentionally Hidden" value="implicitRefCursor metadata='ColumnName=TL_TYPE;
                 BaseSchemaName=CMS_USER;BaseTableName=TBL_LETTER;NativeDataType=varchar2;ProviderType=varchar2;ProviderDBType=String;
                 DataType=System.String;AllowDBNull=true'"/>

      <add name="Intentionally Hidden" value="implicitRefCursor metadata='ColumnName=TL_MODE;BaseSchemaName=CMS_USER;
                 BaseTableName=TBL_LETTER;NativeDataType=char;ProviderType=char;ProviderDBType=String;ColumnSize=1;
                 DataType=System.String;AllowDBNull=true'"/>

      <add name="Intentionally Hidden" value="implicitRefCursor metadata='ColumnName=TL_REMARKS;BaseSchemaName=CMS_USER;
                 BaseTableName=TBL_LETTER;NativeDataType=varchar2;ProviderType=varchar2;ProviderDBType=String;ColumnSize=2000;
                 DataType=System.String;AllowDBNull=true'"/>

      <add name="Intentionally Hidden" value="implicitRefCursor metadata='ColumnName=TL_TASK_ID;BaseSchemaName=CMS_USER;
                 BaseTableName=TBL_LETTER;NativeDataType=varchar2;ProviderType=varchar2;ProviderDBType=String;ColumnSize=50;
                 DataType=System.String;AllowDBNull=true'"/>

      <add name="Intentionally Hidden" value="implicitRefCursor metadata='ColumnName=TEMPLATE_NAME;BaseSchemaName=CMS_USER;
                 BaseTableName=TBL_LETTER;NativeDataType=varchar2;ProviderType=varchar2;ProviderDBType=String;ColumnSize=100;
                 DataType=System.String;AllowDBNull=true'"/>

      <add name="Intentionally Hidden" value="implicitRefCursor metadata='ColumnName=TEMPLATE_PATH;BaseSchemaName=CMS_USER;
                 BaseTableName=TBL_LETTER;NativeDataType=varchar2;ProviderType=varchar2;ProviderDBType=String;ColumnSize=2000;
                 DataType=System.String;AllowDBNull=true'"/>

      <add name="Intentionally Hidden" value="implicitRefCursor metadata='ColumnName=PULL_DART_INVOICE;BaseSchemaName=CMS_USER;
                 BaseTableName=TBL_LETTER;NativeDataType=varchar2;ProviderType=char;ProviderDBType=String;ColumnSize=1;
                 DataType=System.String;AllowDBNull=true'"/>

      <add name="Intentionally Hidden" value="implicitRefCursor metadata='ColumnName=DESCRIPTION;BaseSchemaName=CMS_USER;
                 BaseTableName=TBL_LETTER;NativeDataType=varchar2;ProviderType=varchar2;ProviderDBType=String;ColumnSize=100;
                 DataType=System.String;AllowDBNull=true'"/>

      <add name="Intentionally Hidden" value="implicitRefCursor metadata='ColumnName=TEMPLATE_IDENTIFIER_TYPE;BaseSchemaName=CMS_USER;
                 BaseTableName=TBL_LETTER;NativeDataType=varchar2;ProviderType=varchar2;ProviderDBType=String;ColumnSize=100;
                 DataType=System.String;AllowDBNull=true'"/>
    </settings>
  </oracle.dataaccess.client>
  <appSettings>

    <add key="CCLLetterPath" value="D:\Atlas_Collection_Services\AtlasLetterProcess\Output\CCLLetters\"/>
    <add key="AutoLetterPath" value="D:\Atlas_Collection_Services\AtlasLetterProcess\Output\AutoLetters\"/>
    <add key="OnDemandPath" value="D:\Atlas_Collection_Services\AtlasLetterProcess\Output\OnDemandLetters\"/>
    <add key="AutoStopPath" value="D:\Atlas_Collection_Services\AtlasLetterProcess\Output\AutoStopLetters\"/>
    <add key="XSDPath" value="D:\Atlas_Collection_Services\AtlasLetterProcess\XSD\LetterProcess.xsd"/>
    <add key="LogFilePath" value="D:\Atlas_Collection_Services\AtlasLetterProcess\Log\"/>
    <add key="LogFileName" value="ATLAS_LETTERPROCESS"/>
    <add key="HeaderImage" value="D:\Atlas_Collection_Services\AtlasLetterProcess\Header.jpg"/>
    <add key="DeleteFiles" value="Y"/>
    <add key="ArchivePath" value="D:\Atlas_Collection_Services\AtlasLetterProcess\Archive\"/>
    <!-- Print Center Configurations-->
    <add key="ServerAddress" value="Intentionally Hidden" />
    <add key="UserName" value="Intentionally Hidden" />
    <add key="Password" value="Intentionally Hidden" />
    <add key="LicenseKey" value="Intentionally Hidden" />
    <add key="LicenseOwner" value="Intentionally Hidden" />
    <add key="ChangeWorkingDirectory" value="/collectltr/Prod/" />
    <add key="ServerPort" value="22" />
    <!--Email Details-->
    <add key="SMTPServer" value="Intentionally Hidden" />
    <add key="EmailSupportFrom" value="AtlasLetterProcessProd@Intentionally Hidden"/>
    <add key="EmailSupportTo" value="Intentionally Hidden@Intentionally Hidden"/>
    <add key="EmailSupportCC" value=""/>
    <add key="EmailSupportBCC" value=""/>
    <add key="EmailSubject" value="Atlas LetterProcess(Prod): Error in letter process service."/>
    <add key ="ErrorStartLine" value = "****************** Error Message ******************" />
    <add key ="EndLine" value = "***************************************************" />
    <!--ATLAS-->
    <add key="AtlasUsername" value="Intentionally Hidden" />
    <add key="AtlasPassword" value="Intentionally Hidden" />
    <add key="AtlasSessionType" value="Stateless" />
    <add key="AtlasExpirationHours" value="10" />
    <add key="AtalasServiceURL"  value="http://Intentionally Hidden:8080/eai_enu/start.swe?SWEExtSource=WebService&amp;SWEExtCmd=Execute&amp;WSSOAP=1"/>
    <!--Service Timing-->
    <add key="AutoMode" value="ON" />
    <add key="ServiceStartTime" value="01:00" />
    <add key="ServiceEndTime" value="23:00" />
    <add key="ServiceInterval" value="60000" />
    <add key="ServiceDay" value="1,2,3,4,5,6,0" />
    <!--Mon-1,Tue-2,Wed-3,Thr-4,Fri-5,Sat-6,Sun-0-->
    <!--Dart Service configurations-->
    <add key="DARTServiceURL" value="Intentionally Hidden"/>
    <add key="DartUsername" value="Intentionally Hidden"/>
    <add key="DartPassword" value="Intentionally Hidden"/>
    <add key="PartitionLimit" value="1000" />
    <add key="ExcludeInvoiceCodes" value="78,79,RD,TD,SD" />

  </appSettings>
  <applicationSettings>
    <ATLAS_LETTERPROCESS.Common.Properties.Settings>
      <setting name="ATLAS_LETTERPROCESS_Common_DARTWebService_DARTWebServiceService"
          serializeAs="String">
        <value>Intentionally Hidden</value>
      </setting>
    </ATLAS_LETTERPROCESS.Common.Properties.Settings>
  </applicationSettings>
  <system.web>
    <webServices>
      <soapExtensionTypes>
        <add type="ATLAS_LETTERPROCESS.SoapExtension.SiebelSoapExtension, ATLAS_LETTERPROCESS.SoapExtension" />
      </soapExtensionTypes>
    </webServices>
    <membership defaultProvider="ClientAuthenticationMembershipProvider">
      <providers>
        <add name="ClientAuthenticationMembershipProvider" type="System.Web.ClientServices.Providers.ClientFormsAuthenticationMembershipProvider, System.Web.Extensions, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" serviceUri="" />
      </providers>
    </membership>
    <roleManager defaultProvider="ClientRoleProvider" enabled="true">
      <providers>
        <add name="ClientRoleProvider" type="System.Web.ClientServices.Providers.ClientRoleProvider, System.Web.Extensions, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" serviceUri="" cacheTimeout="86400" />
      </providers>
    </roleManager>
  </system.web>
  <startup>
    <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.0"/>
  </startup>
</configuration>
```

Comment: There is an error in your app.config file

Comment: Show us your exe.config file (appSettings section)

Comment: I have added content from app.config (note: some values are intentionally hidden)

Comment: any help on the issue? Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was able to replicate this issue using a simple console app and using the Config file you have there as App.config.

For example in the console app I have just 2 following lines -

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var configFile = ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration(ConfigurationUserLevel.None);
        var abc = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["abc"];
    }
}
```

After executing the above program I get error as shown below -

```
   at System.Configuration.ClientConfigurationSystem.EnsureInit(String configKey)
   at System.Configuration.ClientConfigurationSystem.PrepareClientConfigSystem(String sectionName)
   at System.Configuration.ClientConfigurationSystem.System.Configuration.Internal.IInternalConfigSystem.GetSection(String sectionName)
   at System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.get_AppSettings()
   at ExperimentConsoleApp.Program.Main(String[] args)
```

But when I look at the inner exception I get can see the following error -

```
Unrecognized configuration section oracle.dataaccess.client.
```

This can be very well because I don't have correct components installed but the configsections is not specifying the component and to validate that I commented out the oracle data access and it works. I also tried to install oracle managed data access component and as expected it added the configuration in config sections of the web.config.

Config sections is missing the oracle data access configuration. For example below is for oracle managed data access -

```xml
<configSections>

    <section name="oracle.manageddataaccess.client"

      type="OracleInternal.Common.ODPMSectionHandler, Oracle.ManagedDataAccess, Version=4.121.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89b483f429c47342" />  

  </configSections>
```

Comment: Using this testing method helped me solve another app.config related issue.